# Appcelerator webview android 5.x prevent system font size change

Tags: android, webview, titanium, appcelerator, font-size

I have found a strange behavior of the application text size when I change the system font size settings on a Appcelerator Studio application.

In iOS and Android < 5.x it works fine. Always I can see fonts without scale. On Android 5.x text inside a WebView and other components like a AlertDialog or TextField, I notice a scaled font size. I want the app respect text size, prevent the OS settings change. I don't know why on Android 5.x don't have the same behavior. Is there a buy? or there are any configuration parameter to avoid this?

I try to get de size of an alert text trying to check the change buy It's no possible. If it not posible to avoid this at least should be something to check if system font size has changed and show an alert to the user.

I already try to set ti.ui.defaultunit on "dp" or other values with the same results.
The Label component don't change the font size in any case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you "change the system font size settings on a Appcelerator Studio application" ?

Comment: The problem occurs when I change system font size from Android Configuration. It isn't possible change the font size by Appccelerator. When I open the app after change it, on Android 5.x change the app font size and lose structure of my design.

Comment: I want to avoid it (the auto-increase of the font in app as a result of  android configuration font size change), like happend on other android versions or iOS with no extra configuration.

Comment: So what you are saying is the on older Android versions the system wide font size setting on Android was ignored by Titanium but in newer Android versions it is not. Could you create a test case and post that as a JIRA ticket? https://jira.appcelerator.org

Comment: It is exactly that I said. In my case is better the behaviour of the older versions of Android, but maybe we should have otions to choose if it's possible. On iOs is ignored too.

Comment: I see you have created a JIRA ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-528. Thanks for that! Like my colleague Jebun asked, could you attach a reproducible test case and environment info/steps?

Comment: I sent a test case about this problem some days ago.  I havn't any solution since today.  If you can help me , I'd appreciate it .

Comment: I don't see a test case at https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-528? With test case I mean read-to-run and as minimal as possible code (or full project attached) plus steps/environment/expectation and actual observation. If you attach that we can reproduce and fix.